# Removing an item in HTML5 Local Storage after a period of time?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a simple HTML5 App that I am currently working on and I'm wondering if it's possible to remove a item in HTML5 Local Storage after a period of time, like: after 24 hours, remove this item, etc.

I'm thinking that Date Object built into JavaScript would probably be what I need.

Is this possible? Some code examples would be nice if you could, thanks!

Answer (score 22):

You could store the date along with the data

```
//add data we are interested in tracking to an array
var values = new Array();
var oneday = new Date();
oneday.setHours(oneday.getHours() + 24); //one day from now
values.push("hello world");
values.push(oneday);
try {
    localStorage.setItem(0, values.join(";"));
} 
catch (e) { }

//check if past expiration date
var values = localStorage.getItem(0).split(";");
if (values[1] < new Date()) {
    localStorage.removeItem(0);
}
```

Comment: I like this solution however I think it should be noted for this particular example that values[1] needs to be parsed into a Date object before its compared. Like this new Date(values[1])

Comment: The date is taken from the user's OS and if the user had tampered with the OS's date settings than he will bypass this

Answer (score 4):

Use This Solution:

```
(function () {

  var lastclear = localStorage.getItem('lastclear'),
      time_now  = (new Date()).getTime();

  // .getTime() returns milliseconds so 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 = 24 days
  if ((time_now - lastclear) > 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) {

    localStorage.clear();

    localStorage.setItem('lastclear', time_now);
  }

})();
```

Comment: who need to stay?! It's check you localStorage if you visit the site in the last X time and remove it if it's bigger.

Comment: I think you mean 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 = 24 hours not 24 days

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this I think you basically have to do it manually. For example, you could store the timestamp in a localStorage slot alongside each value you're storing, and then check the timestamp against the current time at some regular interval like page load or setTimeout or something.

Example:

```
//this function sets the value, and marks the timestamp
function setNewVal(prop)
{
    window.localStorage[prop] = Math.random();
    window.localStorage[prop+"timestamp"] = new Date();
}

//this function checks to see which ones need refreshing
function someRucurringFunction()
{
    //check each property in localStorage
    for (var prop in window.localStorage)
    {   //if the property name contains the string "timestamp"
        if (prop.indexOf("timestamp") != -1)
        {   //get date objects
            var timestamp = new Date(window.localStorage[prop]);
            var currentTime = new Date();

            //currently set to 30 days, 12 hours, 1 min, 1s (don't set to 0!)
            var maxAge =    (1000   *   1)  *//s
                            (60     *   1)  *//m
                            (60     *  12)  *//h
                            (24     *  30);  //d

            if ((currentTime - timestamp) > maxAge)
            {//if the property is too old (yes, this really does work!)
                //get the string of the real property (this prop - "timestamp")
                var propString = prop.replace("timestamp","");
                //send it to some function that sets a new value
                setNewVal(propString);
            }
        }
    }
}
//set the loop
window.setInterval(someRucurringFunction,(1000*60*60);
```

EDIT: mrtsherman's method would totally work as well. Similarly, you could enter the timestamp as a property of an object you might be storing/retrieving with JSON.stringify/parse(). If either the array or the object are very large, or you have very many of them, I'd probably suggest using the parallel property method for efficiency, though.

Comment: You should use `(new Date).getTime()` when storing in *localhost* and comparing

Answer (score -6):

```
window.setInterval(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('nicwincount', 0);
},8640000); //24 * 60mins * 60sec
```

ps: nicwincount is a localstorage you set before. 
localStorage.setItem('feeds', Ext.encode(feeds));

hope can help you.

Comment: Doesn't this assume the device remains on the page for 24 hours? Unlikely! ;-)